# Hittest polygon

Tags: polygon, collision, hittest

I have a 2d polygon that consists of a list with points, i want to check wether a given point lies in that polygon, but i cant find a good way to check this.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://alienryderflex.com/polygon/
this is a very very clear guide how to do that, inclusive a implementation in C

Answer (score 3):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon